# Preserving order in property file while it's being updated

Tags: java

I am trying to modify my existing property file using Properties class methods. The file is getting updated but it does not maintain property order. As for example, if I have data like this:

```
baseurl=stackoverflow.com
user_id=hello
pass=test123
```

After updating the file it's not maintaining key=value pairs. Updated file contents change sometimes as below:

```
pass=test123
baseurl=stackexchange.com
user_id=hell0222
```

I want my data preserve order as it was before updating. Please suggest me if any of you know how to preserve order in property file.

Comment: Properties is a Hashtable, and Hashtables don't have any order. You'll have to do that by yourself.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312383/pulling-values-from-a-java-properties-file-in-order

Comment: Why do you care? Order isn't significant in a properties file.

Comment: Since I've to maintain the order. @EJP

Comment: @optimist_creeper Reiterating the requirement doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I am not reiterating. I am told to preserve the order while updating the file. Don't mind.

Comment: @EJP when you are maintaining resource bundles you don't want to mess up the order because messages next to each other are there because of there shared context. But maybe some automatic process is there to fill in missing keys. So this shouldn't mess everything up.

Comment: In that case I would use an existing *editor* to edit the properties file, instead of writing a Java application that cannot possibly meet the requirements.